# Javascript visualforce upload file issue

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, actionfunction

I'm attempting to upload a file through a VF command link and action function [working on old unmanaged package :-( ]. For multiple rows in pageblocktable. I am having trouble deciding the id for each upload. Following is what I tried. Currently, only the first content version upload works, not working for any other upload.

JS

```
   <script>
    var maxStringSize = 6000000;
    var attachmentList;
    var j;
    function uploadMe(ele)
    {
        input = document.getElementById('fileinput');
        var varName =  ele.getAttribute("accesskey");
        attachmentList = input.files;
        console.log("attachmentList",attachmentList);
        console.log("varName",varName);//
        if(j == undefined) 
        j = 0;   
        var file;
        if(j < attachmentList.length)
        {
            file = attachmentList[j];
            var name = file.name;
            var reader = new FileReader();  
            reader.onload = function(e) {  
             var attachmentbodybase64 = reader.result.replace(/^data:.+;base64,/, '');//console log will print : ZGF0YTppbWFnZS9wbmc7YmFzZTY0LGlWQk9SdzB.....
                console.log(attachmentbodybase64.length);
                if(attachmentbodybase64.length > maxStringSize )
                alert("File size is too large to handle");
                else
                {
                    j++;
                    //saveFileAF(attachmentbodybase64, name);
                    saveFileAF(attachmentbodybase64, name, varName);
                }
            }
             reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('this is end');
            
        }
        
     }
</script>
```

Following is the vf

```
 <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
 <input type= "file" Id= "fileinput"/>
   <apex:commandButton onclick="uploadMe(this);return false;" value="Upload" accesskey="{!wrapperTask.position}"/>
 </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
 </apex:column>
```

Action function:

```
        <apex:actionFunction name="saveFileAF" action="{!upload}" reRender="dm">
            <apex:param name="base64File" value="" assignTo="{!base64}"/>
            <apex:param name="fileName" value="" assignTo="{!fileName}"/>
            <apex:param name="taskPos" value="" assignTo="{!taskPosition}"/>
        </apex:actionFunction>
```

Apex:

```
public void upload() {
    
    system.debug('@@fileName' +this.fileName);
    system.debug('@@this.refId'+this.refId);

    ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
    cv.Title = this.filename;
    cv.PathOnClient = this.fileName;
    cv.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64decode(this.base64);
    cv.IsMajorVersion = true;
    Database.SaveResult sr=Database.insert(cv);         
    
    system.debug('@@cv id' +cv.Id); //gives me the id of content version
    system.debug('@@taskPosition id' +this.taskPosition);//gives me the 0th position of the upload from accesskey.
    
    mapTaskPositionContentId.put(cv.Id,this.taskPosition);//printing this gives me (qwqwe18digitID, 0), zero being the position of the upload file.        
  
}
```

Here's the UI of the vf upload I trying to upload:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the first row file gets uploaded because of this line in your JS:

```
input = document.getElementById('fileinput');
```

All rows have the same id for input-file element and so the first one gets picked.

I modified the code a bit to have an index in the id attribute and pass it as a parameter in the JS function.

**VF Code:**

```
<apex:form>
   <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="index"/>
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! accounts }" var="a">
         <apex:column>
            <apex:outputText>
               <apex:variable value="{!index + 1}" var="index" />
               {!index}
            </apex:outputText>
         </apex:column>
         <apex:column>
            <input type= "file" Id= "fileinput{!index}"/>
            <apex:commandButton onclick="uploadMe('{!index}');" value="Upload"/>
         </apex:column>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
   </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

**JS Code:**

```
<script>
var maxStringSize = 6000000;
var attachmentList;
var j;

function uploadMe(index) {
    var fileId = 'fileinput' + index //Add index to identify row no.
    input = document.getElementById(fileId);
    attachmentList = input.files;
    console.log("attachmentList", attachmentList);
    if (j == undefined)
        j = 0;
    var file;
    if (j < attachmentList.length) {
        file = attachmentList[j];
        var name = file.name;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var attachmentbodybase64 = reader.result.replace(/^data:.+;base64,/, ''); //console log will print : ZGF0YTppbWFnZS9wbmc7YmFzZTY0LGlWQk9SdzB.....
            console.log(attachmentbodybase64.length);
            if (attachmentbodybase64.length > maxStringSize)
                alert("File size is too large to handle");
            else {
                j++;
                //saveFileAF(attachmentbodybase64, name);
                saveFileAF(attachmentbodybase64, name, varName);
            }
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else {
        console.log('this is end');

    }

}
</script>
```

See if this helps!